# Keras ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 32, 17) vs (None, 17))

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I am training a multi-label classifier(handwritten digit recogniser on IAM dataset).

Here are shapes of all of my splits:

```
>>> X_train.shape, X_val.shape, X_test.shape, Y_train.shape, Y_val.shape,  Y_test.shape
((86583, 32, 128, 1),
 (4558, 32, 128, 1),
 (4797, 32, 128, 1),
 (86583, 17),
 (4558, 17),
 (4797, 17))
```

Here is how 5 examples of target variable would look like:

```
>>> Y_val[5:10]
array([[68, 59,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
         0],
       [28, 67, 57,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
         0],
       [42, 59, 59, 62, 56, 58,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
         0],
       [73, 61, 58,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
         0],
       [73, 61, 54, 73,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
         0]], dtype=int32)
```

(in above array, each number corresponds to index in characters & alphabet list. And zeroes have been padded for all target vectors to match the size of biggest target word.)

And I am using 'sigmoid' activation at output layer with 17 units, each for one possible output character/alphabet, as shown below.

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers
     .
     .
layers.Dense(units=17, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', kernel_regularizer='l2')
```

with 'binary_crossentropy' as loss, for my multi-label classification problem.

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
```

Here's my error:
[image]

EDIT 1:
Architecture of my model:
[image]

Comment: Your error is likely to come from another part of your model, can you show it completely?

Comment: You want to see the architecture of my model?

Comment: Yes, please parse it

Comment: I have added it.

Comment: It would be simpler to see the code, but the issue comes from your second LSTM layer, by any chance, have you set `return_sequences=True`?

Comment: Yes, I have set `return_sequences=True` for both the LSTM layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `return_sequences=True` from your second LSTM layer and that should do it